# How do I add order information from Google Checkout into my database?

Tags: asp.net, google-checkout

I have implemented Google Checkout sandbox for testing buy button which successfully allows user to place their orders. I want to add order of Google Checkout sandbox to my database by using asp.net.

Can anyone tell me how can I implement this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple interfaces to Google Checkout .  By far the easiest is a buy now button, which is what it sounds like you've implemented.  Now the limitation with that method is that it places one item into a cart at Google and that's the end of the interaction.  So you need to process the order in the Merchant center.  Nice and simple for small sites processing few orders.  But doesn't sound like what you want.  At the other end of the spectrum, you can do a custom cart using the html or xml interfaces.  Using the xml interface, you have complete control of the order.  Google will then do call backs on complete order to post the cart back to your site.  Taken to the extreme, you can automate pretty much anything that could be done in the merchant center: canceling orders, issuing refunds, etc.

It's all a question of trading off integration effort with control.  They offer a number of different integration patterns.  There's a [nice comparison](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Comparison_Part_II.html) on in the developer docs.  But with the buy now buttons, I don't believe that anything ever comes back to your system, and it sounds like you want the order details back on your system/site.  You may also want to take a look at [Ways to integrate with Google Checkout](https://checkout.google.com/seller/integrate.html) and pick the integration pattern that makes the most sense for you.

I don't have ASP.Net code to hand you, but I'm sure it's doable and there are examples in the developer docs.

Answer (score 0):

See this site for Checkout Client Libraries & Sample Code (including .NET and Classic ASP):

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/samplecode.html